# Android Why OS issues onPause()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onresume, onpause

My `Activity` creates an `AsyncTask` that loads data from a file and updates the UI on `onProgressUpdate()`, classic book `AsyncTask`.
But Android is putting the Activity `onPause()` right after the `AsyncTask` is launched.

I am trying to understand why (and how to prevent it)

This causes all `AsyncTask` UI updates to stop; then, when the `AsyncTask` finishes, the `Activity` does not resume by itself, I have to touch the screen or press some Action bar button to get it to `onResume()`

EDIT:
This is the logcat, (using aLogcat app to get it)

< To be updated with new complete log >

Temporary (first onPause() after file chooser):

```
06-12 22:08:48.744 11302 11302 D Viewer: + optionsItemSelected(itemID:2131296267)
06-12 22:08:48.754 11302 11302 D Viewer: + showFileChooser(path:/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.delphi.app/files, requestCode:0)
06-12 22:08:48.754 11302 11302 D Viewer: + onResume()
06-12 22:08:48.754 11302 11302 D Viewer: + onSaveInstanceState(outState:Bundle[{}])
06-12 22:08:48.754 11302 11302 D Viewer: + onPause()
06-12 22:08:48.754   189   443 I ActivityManager: START {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras)} from pid 11302
06-12 22:08:48.764   189   489 D WindowManager: adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 0mcc0mnc (no locale) layoutdir=0 sw800dp w800dp h1232dp xlrg port ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidOpen:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
06-12 22:08:48.764 11302 11304 D dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 244K, 5% free 6748K/7047K, paused 2ms+3ms
```

Temporary (second onPause() , the probelmatic one):

```
06-12 22:09:00.324 11302 11350 I LoaderTask: Publishing message 13
06-12 22:09:00.324 11302 11350 I LoaderTask: Adding message 14
06-12 22:09:00.324 11302 11350 I LoaderTask: Publishing message 14
06-12 22:09:00.354 11302 11350 I LoaderTask: Adding message 15
06-12 22:09:00.354 11302 11302 D MessageTable: + onLayout(changed:false, l:0, t:0, r:800, b:20)
06-12 22:09:00.354 11302 11350 I LoaderTask: Publishing message 15
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageTable: + getColumns()
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageTable: + getRowCount()
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageTable: + getRowAt(index:-1)
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageRow: + getColumns()
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageTable: + setHeaderColumns(cols:[I@41125668)
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D MessageRow: + setColumns(cols:[I@41125668)
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D Viewer: + onSaveInstanceState(outState:Bundle[{}])
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D Viewer: + onPause()
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D LoaderTask: + getState()
06-12 22:09:00.364 11302 11302 D LoaderTask: + pause()
06-12 22:09:00.364   189   489 D WindowManager: adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 0mcc0mnc (no locale) layoutdir=0 sw800dp w800dp h1232dp xlrg port ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidOpen:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
```

App structure, added upon request:

```
MainActivity
    Launch Viewer Activity on Button click

Viewer Activity
    Show layout, has a MessageTable (TableLayout)
    Launch ShowFileChosser  to choose a Records file
    Execute LoaderTask with given file

LoaderTask
    Open given file
    doInBackground()    
        Read one record
        Add the record to an ArrayList
        if not paused Publish record
    onProgressUpdate()
        Show record in MessageTable
```

Comment: Without seeing some code, it is difficult to assist you.

Comment: Capturing and posting the logcat log could be very helpful.

Comment: are you showing any progress dialog in the `onPreExecute()`?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild I am afraid the code is too large to post here

Comment: @ChrisStratton I added the logcat, you can see the pause and the Task keeps updating for a while. :::: 
The opened file has 337 records, but you can see it stops onProgrssUpdate() on record 107 (this is because the onPause on the Viewer call to pause the task UI update too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
06-12 18:21:09.394 9512 9512 D Viewer: + onStop()
06-12 18:21:14.684 9512 9512 D Viewer: + onActivityResult(requestCode:0, resultCode:-1, data:Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/Records.11111.MyLog.gzip })
```

You've filtered the logcat so it's hard to see all of what is happening, but it looks like you are using an Intent to get something (a filename?) from another activity during this 5 second gap.

You should expect an onPause()-onResume() cycle anytime you transfer to another activity.

Comment: You're right! I just saw I had  "+ on" filter on the aLogcat, I will run again and update the log

Comment: The new log is 750 lines long, I am not sure what are the rules regarding posting large pieces of code. Can I just put it in the questioin body?

Comment: 'You should expect an onPause()-onResume() cycle anytime you transfer to another activity.' :::: Does this include a child AsyncTask?, the emulator did not produce any onPause() under the same input.

Comment: I think you had better show the code of the AsyncTask.  Where is file path data in the the onActivityResult() call quoted above coming from?

Comment: I am afraid the code is also some 900 lines. :::: The file path data comes from a file chooser intent. The Asynctask reads records from the file in the background as I explain in the question body.:::: As each record is read the UI is updated. :::: All this works 100% fine in the emulator (two of them actually a 2.2 and a 4.0 emulators) :::: Do you have any knowledge what heuristic is used  by Android to issue a Pause event? :::: This is the only app launched in the device, so it was not preempted ::::

Comment: "The file path data comes from a file chooser intent." Anytime you use an Intent to launch something else, your activity should receive an onPause().

Comment: You surely mean BEFORE I choose the file, it makes sense, and I see it on the logcat. But AFTER I choose the file, the app continues. :::: In the logcat I have (still to be added to the question) I get a second onPause, right in the middle of the AsyncTask work, while updating the UI (I will put a few lines in the question so you can see, until I find the way to post it all)

Comment: I could only go by what you had posted.  It would help a lot if you made your log tags have a 1-1 correspondence to activities.  Also, please log onDestroy() and onCreate() and clarify if the "LoaderTask: + pause()" is also an onPause().

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what is the cause of multiple onPause() calls. In my case there are multiple calls to ShowFileChooser().

As Chris Stratton pointed out, after transfer to another activity there is onPause(), in this case after calling ShowFileChooser().
The Viewer activiy is stopped while I choose a file (onStop() is called) and then restarted according to the well know activity life cycle. It is then when ShowFilechooser is called  again, generating a second pause/stop.

I am granting the answer to Chris, since his comments led me to think and rethink until I caught what was happening.